# Configure keystore for soap web service in Glassfish - How to?

Tags: java, security, soap, glassfish, ws-security

I been using Tomcat as application server for deploying my web services, using metro.

- I use Mutual Certificate authentication (Message Level Security).
- I created my own Credential Authority, Server key pair and Client key pair.
- I have a 'wsit-.xml' file in my resources/META-INF folder with the WS-* configurations, including keystore and truststore location and password.

Everything works great!

But today I tried to create a new project but now for Glassfish (3.1.1). using the same keystore, truststore and config file. But now I receave an Exception: "Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors".

- It is possible to use the keystore in the project instead of one from Glassfish?
- If not, how do I configure my key pair in glassfish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appars that Glassfish doesn't use the wsit configuration files, so the keys in the project.

It is necessary to add your key-pair to keystore.jks in conf folder in the domain directory. Also the is a cacerts.jks, where you need to add the certificates you would put in your truststore.

You need to condigure the domain.xml and add under the soap section, the configuration for youe key alias.